# How to Add 'rest_registration' URLs to Default Routers in Django REST Framework and Include Them in API Root?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am using the '**rest_registration**' package to handle user validation and registration in my Django REST API project. I would like to integrate the 'rest_registration' URLs with the **default routers** in Django REST Framework and have them included in the **API root**.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this integration? Specifically, I want to know how to configure my project to include 'rest_registration' URLs in the default routers, and I'd like these URLs to be visible in the API root.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ServerStatusViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        return Response({'status': 'Server is running'})

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'status', ServerStatusViewSet, basename='server-status')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', include('rest_registration.api.urls')),
]
```